# JNDI in Stateless Bean not found in Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jndi, wildfly-10

I am using wildfly 10.

For some reason I've got error like this:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ServiceAImpl-- service jboss.naming.context.java.global.ServiceAImpl: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ServiceAImpl -- service
```

The way that I access to jndi:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:global/");
IWorker worker = (IWorker) context.lookup("ServiceAImpl");
worker.createTimer(task);
```

rest of code:

```
public interface IWorker{

    void createTimer(ExecutableTask aExecutableTask);
}

@Stateless
@Local(IServiceA.class)
public class IServiceAImpl
        implements IServiceA {

    @Override
    public void createTimer(ExecutableTask aExecutableTask) {

        System.out.println("I am doing some jobs");
    }
}


@Local
public interface IServiceAextends IWorker{


}
```

How can I get access to this IWorker? How to get this JNDI?

Comment: When your wildfly starts, it logs the JNDI entries in the console. You can find your correct JNDI there. Could you post your log too?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JNDI+Reference). You are going to find something similar to this in your Wildfly logs when it is starting.

```
java:global/<your-project>/bus-facade-fumo/WUFFacade!<your-project>.wuf.WUFFacadeRemote
java:app/bus-facade-<your-project>/WUFFacade!<your-project>.wuf.WUFFacadeRemote
java:module/WUFFacade!<your-project>.wuf.WUFFacadeRemote
java:jboss/exported/<your-project>/bus-facade-<your-project>/WUFFacade!<your-project>.wuf.WUFFacadeRemote
java:global/<your-project>/bus-facade-<your-project>/WUFFacade
java:app/bus-facade-<your-project>/WUFFacade
java:module/WUFFacade
```

So you can find the JNDIs you need in your console logs, just like the example above. In you case, you are almost there, but you have to complete this piece of code with the complete information:

`Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:global/<HereYouNeedMoreInformation>");`